# Play sound in C# on button press

Tags: c#, windows

I've tried to play a sound from a button event handler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void mainButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\mywavfile.wav");
            player.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error where the type or namespace "media" does not exist in the namespace "system". What seems to be the problem?

I'm using visual studio 2017 and I've created a universal windows c# blank app.

Edit:

I've changed my code to this but I'm still not getting any audio playback.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void mainButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement PlayMusic = new MediaElement();
            PlayMusic.AudioCategory = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AudioCategory.Media;
            PlayMusic.Source = new Uri(@"D:/Downloads/sounds.mp3");
            PlayMusic.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried adding a background declaration tho to allow background audio but still to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using .Net Core and System.Media is in .Net Framework.

In .Net Core you could use Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement. Alternatively you could use Windows.Media.Audio.AudioGraph.

Comment: wow how did you know this? did you actually do research or was it obvious to you?

Comment: I am busy writting a UWP app for Video Tagging so just been through all of this myself.

Comment: I've updated the answer, still couldn't get audio to play. I've tried the MediaElement method

Comment: Assuming you have a grid in your XAML as such <Grid x:Name="rootGrid" ... you need to add the media element as follows "rootGrid.AddChild(PlayMusic);"